# Node Auto Instrumentations not working correctly when deployed

Tags: open-telemetry

I am having issues with the getNodeAutoInstrumentations() metapackage.
For some reason, when the application is deployed I stop getting incoming and outgoing http metrics. Locally everything is working.

Setting the `OTEL_LOG_LEVEL` to `DEBUG` gives some hint on what is going on. Locally the logs show all instrumentations being applied (including the insturmentation-http and express), but on production there is only logs for instrumentation-fs and instrumentation-pg. Others are not being applied.
Here is the code I am using. Any help would be useful. Thanks

```
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { PrometheusExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus';

const sdk = new NodeSDK({
    metricReader: new PrometheusExporter({}, () => {
        console.log(
            `OpenTelemetry prometheus scrape endpoint: http://localhost:${PrometheusExporter.DEFAULT_OPTIONS.port}${PrometheusExporter.DEFAULT_OPTIONS.endpoint}`,
        );
    }),
    instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});

sdk.start();
```

And this is what the final compiled code looks like on the VM.

```
'use strict';

var autoInstrumentationsNode = require('@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node');
-----
other imports
-----

function _interopDefaultLegacy (e) { return e && typeof e === 'object' && 'default' in e ? e : { 'default': e }; }

function _interopNamespace(e) {
    if (e && e.__esModule) return e;
    var n = Object.create(null);
    if (e) {
        Object.keys(e).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k !== 'default') {
                var d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, k);
                Object.defineProperty(n, k, d.get ? d : {
                    enumerable: true,
                    get: function () { return e[k]; }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    n["default"] = e;
    return Object.freeze(n);
}

var Router__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(Router);
var Docker__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(Docker);
var esb__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(esb);
var winston__namespace = /*#__PURE__*/_interopNamespace(winston);
var fetch__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(fetch);

const sdk = new sdkNode.NodeSDK({
  metricReader: new exporterPrometheus.PrometheusExporter({}, () => {
    console.log(
      `OpenTelemetry prometheus scrape endpoint: http://localhost:${exporterPrometheus.PrometheusExporter.DEFAULT_OPTIONS.port}${exporterPrometheus.PrometheusExporter.DEFAULT_OPTIONS.endpoint}`
    );
  }),
  instrumentations: [autoInstrumentationsNode.getNodeAutoInstrumentations()]
});
sdk.start();
```